# Use taylors theorem with integral reminder to prove log(1+x) uniformly converge

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Use taylors theorem with integral reminder to prove 
$log(1+x)=x-\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^3}{3}+...$ uniformly converge for on every $[-a,a]$ where $0<a<1$.

i have computed the $R_n=\frac{1}{n!}\int_{0}^{x}(-1)^{n+1}\frac{(x-t)^n}{(1+t)^{n+1}}$.

However i dont know how to prove the supnorm $\lim_{n\to\infty} ||R_n||=0$

Please help. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

First of all,your $R_n$ should not be in terms of $x$ in the integral part.
I think after computation, $R_n=\int_{0}^{x}\frac{t^n}{(1+t)^{n+1}}dt$

And a little hint for the remaining part.

Notice that $|R_n|\leq a^n$ independent from the choice of $x$.

Therefore the uniform convergence of series is established by the fact that $lim(a^n)=0$

Comment: Thanks for your reply! As i found in wiki, the reminder is $R_{k}(x)=\int _{a}^{x}{\frac {f^{(k+1)}(t)}{k!}}(x-t)^{k}\,dt.$ Am i correct? So there will be a x in the integral?

Comment: Oh! Your $R_n$ is indeed correct. I have make some mistake in computation. But never mind, the hint for remaining part still works.

Comment: May i know how you derive $|R_n|<a^n$ ? Thank you so much

Comment: We may do it by separating $R_n$ into two case. One for non-negative x and one for negative x.

Comment: For $0\leq x$ we would have $\frac{(x-t)^n}{(1+t)^{(n+1)}}\leq (x-t)^n$ as $(1+t)^{(n+1)}>1$ therefore $|R_n| \leq a^n$by integrating the bound of $|R_n|$ and you may finish the negative case by sub u=-x